# Java Applet With DLL Files

Tags: java, dll, applet, digital-signature, pkcs#11

I have a java program that use PKCS11 and read digital certificates from e-token. This program uses libpkcs11wrapper.dll file. Program runs perfectly fine on local machine. But when I access it via server it gave me error that libpkcs11wrapper.dll file not found. **So my question is how I can load the dll file on client machine from server?** I have signed the applet. And here is the code which is giving error

```
File jarPath = new File(applicationPath);
        if (!jarPath.isDirectory()) {
            jarPath = jarPath.getParentFile();
        }

    File pkcs11wrapperFile = new File(jarPath, "libpkcs11wrapper" + arch + ".dll");
    System.out.println("Absolute path is "+pkcs11wrapperFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Pkcs11Shell pkcs11Shell = new Pkcs11Shell(pkcs11wrapperFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Download the file then load it perhaps?

Comment: how? program tries to download file from client machine path. this is the problem

Comment: Where are the JavaDocs for `Pkcs11Shell`?

Comment: Why we need a javaDocs here?

Comment: Pkcs11Shell is available in jar and I added into project.